# How to use scope session?

Tags: java, spring, session, scope, javabeans

My project actual using spring + gradle + thymeleaf system, I want to know **how to initiate a bean when I login with another user?**
I tried

```
public class UserData{
List<Questions> questions;
String message;
}
 //in my @Configuration class

   @Bean
   @Scope(proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value="session")
   @ScopedProxy
    public AdminData adminData(){
       return new AdminData();
    }

In my controller, I inject AdminData

    @Controller
    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/question")
    public class QuestionAdminController {

       @Autowired
       private UserData userData;
    }
```

But it doesn't work, the bean is not initialized. 
My WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is defined like:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http.csrf().disable(); // temporary disabled for testing file upload
http.headers().frameOptions().disable(); // disabled for h2 console
// Roles permissions        
http.authorizeRequests()
        // Directories access permissions
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
        // All user can access to new routes at the root
        .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
        // Other requests need the login
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        // Configure the login page
     .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
     .successHandler(customSuccessHandler).permitAll()
        // Default logout from Spring Security
        .and().logout().permitAll()
        .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .maximumSessions(1).expiredUrl("/login?expired");
```

}

I'm not sure that here the session will be expired after log out.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the @EnableAspectJAutoProxy in the @configuration class? The @scope annotation requires that the spring aop is active in your projects

Comment: I didn't add this, but even i add it, the parameter still keep the same value